# How to have two keys and one value in a dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

i'm making a small login system that uses a simple dictionary to store account names and passwords. I was wondering is it possible to have emails and username and then have a password that works for both. 
For example, my only account is 'hello' with a password of 'h1', how can i make it so that 'hello@mail.com' or 'hello' will unlock with a password of 'h1'?

```
accounts = {'hello':'h1'}
print(accounts)
started = ""
while started != "q":
    started = input("Are you a registered user y/n: (if you want to quit press any key)")  

if started == "n": 
     createLogin = input("Create your desired login name: ")

     if createLogin in accounts: 
         print ("Login name already exist!")
     else:
         createPassw = input("Create your desired password password: ")
         accounts[createLogin] = createPassw
         print("User created!")
         addemail = input("What is your email address :")
         accounts[createLogin].append(addemail)             

elif started == "y": 
    login = input("Enter your login name: ")

    if login in accounts:
        passw = input("Enter your password")

    else:
        print("user doesnt exist.")




    if login in accounts and accounts[login] == passw:
        print("Login successful!")
        changepassword = input("Would you like to change your password?")
        if changepassword in ["Y", "y"]:
            newpassw = input("What do you want your new password to be?")
            accounts[login] = newpassw
            print("password succesfully changed!")
        else:
            print("Password was not changed.")
    else:
        print("Incorrect password!")
```

I was trying to append the email to the username so the dictionary would look something like {['hello@mail.com,'hello']:'h1'}.
Any ideas?

Comment: @BanishedBot Would i still be able to make it so if i enter the username or email, i can use the same password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean here?

```
     accounts[createLogin].append(addemail)
```

That of course does not work, because the value is string and string has no `.append`. Also it would make no tense to have email appended to a password.

I think this is not a good structure: `{['hello@mail.com,'hello']:'h1'}`

I would make `accounts` a list of dicts:

```py
accounts = [
    {
        'email': 'hello@mail.com', 
        'username': 'hello', 
        'password': 'h1',
    },
]
```

Then you can look if there are any accounts with given username or email (I'll use function, hope that's OK):

```py
def find_account_by_login(accounts, login):
    for account in accounts:
        if account['email'] == login or account['username'] == login:
            return account
    # no account matched the login
    return None
```

```py
elif started == "y": 
    login = input("Enter your login name: ")
    account = find_account_by_login(accounts, login)
    if not account:
        print("user doesnt exist.")
    else:
        passw = input("Enter your password")
        if passw != account['password']:
            print("Incorrect password!")
        else:
            print("Login successful!")
            # change the password...
```

Comment: Okay so if i use a list of dicts, how do i check each variable in the dict inside the list so that i can't enter a username and then use a different users password?

Answer (score -1):

You could use tuples <s>or lists</s> (see comments) as keys in the dictionary, but that is probably more work and data storage than is worth it.

It may be easier to check the provided user name and if it looks like an email, use the email, and if it doesn't, append a default.

The big problem with this system is "hello", "hello@gmail.com", and "hello@yahoo.com" would check against the same password.

Comment: You can't have lists as keys because they are not hashable.

Comment: Oh. Right. Tuples work, lists don't. Thanks for catching that.